# How do I dynamically generate URLs?

Tags: php

I wan't to know how can i convert a URL to php.

This is last part of the link :

```
www.example.com/index.php?id=2
```

Can i use php to echo the ID?

Comment: echo $_GET['id']; all value passed in this way, you can get by reading the elements in the array $ _GET

Comment: $_GET['var_name'] http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GET['id'];
```

Also you can set a variable to it as well.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

print($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display `id = 4` use the following:

```
<?php
echo 'id ='.$_GET['id'];
?>
```

`.` permits to concat your string `'id ='` and the value of your variable `$_GET['id']`